# External Javascript file not loading

Tags: javascript

I have a external third party js file that doesn't load in IE 9 or 8.  When viewing the network tab in developer tools, it shows a result of ABORTED.  The details are listed as:

> Download initiated by the tokenization of the 'src' attribute of a 'script' element

and

> This download occurred as a speculative download during HTML preparsing.

I've searched high and low with these terms with very VERY few results.  I've tried adding the script dynamically and changing it's location in the layout file, but nothing allows the file to load.

This problem doesn't occur in other browsers, and I've opened up the security settings on IE hoping it was a browser setting.

Any insight or solutions is greatly appreciated.

EDITs:

No I cannot see the source code.  While the script is listed in the dropdown of scripts, it doesn't display any code in developer tools.  I've tried stripping out meta tags and even the doctype (using html 5), but none have moved the bar.

script tag:
(I'm not including the actually URL to protect the innocent.)

```
<script src="https://www.internetbankingcompany.org/onlineserv/HB/Signon.cgi?remote=TRUE" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It is a script provided by a third party financial institutions company, so I'm hesitant to reveal vendor names.  The vendor is not very helpful at all either.

Comment: Can we see the relevant source code?  Have you tried stripping out parts of your page until you narrowed down what else was causing the problem?

Comment: What does your script tag look like?

Comment: Which jquery version and which third party??

Comment: If i remember right this happens in IE when it is guessing the content type or encoding, and then recognizes that it is not the correct one. But honestly i'm not sure if it is about the wrong charset or the wrong mime type or both.

Comment: Have you tried a very simple HTML file with only the script tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery's `getScript` try something like this:

```
  $.getScript('script.js')
  .done(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    console.log(textStatus);
  })
  .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    console.log(exception);
  });
```

What do you get? Does any callback get executed?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, once the issue started getting reported for Chrome, I knew this had to be a settings issue.  I've solved this by unchecking the USE TLS 1.2 option in the advanced Internet Options, and the script is loading now.